# margin between image and text

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

In this code I added an image before the button text I'd like to have a space between the image and text but the code I have isn't working.

```
  <Button Height="25" 
          Width="80" 
          Margin="5,10,5,10"
          Command="{Binding PreviewTemplateCommand}">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="15" Width="63">
              <Image Source="/UILibrary;component/Themes/Default/Images/preview.PNG" 
                     Height="15" Width="15" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
              <TextBlock >Preview</TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
  </Button>
```

Comment: You say "some space between button and image" - do you mean to add space between the text and the image or between the edges of the button and the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you have to set the left margin of the textblock. Try this:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="15" Width="63">
                <Image Source="..." Height="15" Width="15" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Margin="25,0,0,0">Preview</TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>
```